# Can not enter values in rich:inplaceInput tag on Chrome version 45.0.2454.85 m

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom-events, richfaces

When I update Chrome to version 45.0.2454.85 m. I cannot enter values in `rich:inplaceInput` tag (inside `rich:dataTable`):

```
<rich:dataTable
    value="#{viewProductWarehouseProductList.listProductSelected}"
    var="_product" id="tableProductSelected" reRender="ds"
    onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#D3DBDE'"
    onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}'">
    ........
    <rich:column style="width: 10%; text-align : right;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Đơn giá" />
        </f:facet>
        <rich:inplaceInput value="#{_product.priceOutString}"
            minInputWidth="100px" id="priceOut">
            <a:support event="onviewactivated"
                reRender="totalAmount,amountBeforeTaxTotal,amountVat,totalMoney,discountAmount, commissionAmountField, formContractDetail:commissionAmountField:commissionAmount, commissionInput, totalAmountConvert, realPrice, priceOut, contractPriceField"
                actionListener="#{viewProductWarehouseProductList.renderMoney(contractsHome.instance.exchangeRate)}"
                action="#{viewProductWarehouseProductList.calculatorCommission}"
                ajaxSingle="true" />
        </rich:inplaceInput>
    </rich:column>
    ........
</rich:dataTable>
```

I founded link say about change on chrome 45.0.2454.85 m.
[Stable Channel Update](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.ca/2015/09/stable-channel-update.html)
and log [Log change chrome 44.0.2403.157..45.0.2454.85](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/44.0.2403.157..45.0.2454.85?pretty=fuller&n=10000)
But I don't know where is the problem, I think Chrome improved Javascipt (V8) because I can't enter values (I never seen that problem before).

Answer (score 1):

Error accpets only one char if presses backspace two times deletes full input
bug opened:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528900